# knowledge which error of pure virtual function

Tags: c++

I want to configure a pure virtual function named draw in a class called "Shape".
Now, I configure another class called circle that inherits from class "Shape" and I don't implement the draw function at all.

My question is - the error will be a runtime error or a compile error?

Comment: Just try it and see. SO is not a code simulator. Also, documentation on the language should make clear which option is true.

Comment: What's your rationale behind each option?  Also ask yourself what the purpose is of using pure virtual functions.

Answer (score 3):

As described, it will not be a runtime error but a compile time error if you try to instantiate `circle`.

This will compile and run fine:

```
class Shape {
public:
    virtual void draw() const = 0;
};

class circle : public Shape {
};

int main() {}
```

but if you change `main` to

```
int main() {
    circle c;
}
```

you will get a compilation error. Something like `error: cannot declare variable 'c' to be of abstract type 'circle'`

It *is* however possible to get runtime errors too. Here, the pure virtual method will be called because during the construction of `Shape`, `this` will *not* point to a `circle` but a `Shape`:

```
class Shape {
public:
    Shape() {
        foo();
    }
    void foo() {
        draw();
    }
    virtual void draw() const = 0;
};

class circle : public Shape {
    void draw() const override {}
};

int main() {
    circle c;
}
```

Comment: fwiw, there are situations where pure virtual functions can cause a runtime error (during construction/destruction), though not sure if this is beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Indeed - I added that too just in case.